# Send an object via HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

I'm trying to Access following WebAPI controller method via HTTP method

```
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Users/Signin")]  
    [ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
    public bool UserSingIn(User obj)
    {
        bool isuserexit = _usersRepo.UserSignIn(obj);
        if (isuserexit == true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

this is the HTTP method I'm trying to use send `User obj` object,

```
    private string USER_URL = "http://localhost:3623/api/Users";

    public bool GetUser(User obj)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(USER_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("Users/Signin", obj).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result;
            return false;

        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

But this is ending with `response : {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', ..}`

Comment: I think you have to add `/Signin` in your URL.

Comment: You're making a HTTP PUT request to a GET endpoint.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I put `[HttpPut]` then getting `"Internal Server Error"`

Comment: @Div you're saying add like this `.PutAsJsonAsync("Users/Signin/"`

Comment: @kez I'm saying to make changes to the base UR to `Signin` only and `client.PostAsync` `api/Users`

Answer (score 1):

Your Web API only handles GET requests by default. You need to decorate it with the `HttpPut` attribute if you want to use that.

```
[HttpPut]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/Users/Signin")]  
[ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
public bool UserSingIn(User obj)
```

Comment: then I'm getting `"Internal Server Error"`

Comment: @kez Debug your Web API. It should throw an exception and you can read what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postAsync method.

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSave);
var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var resp = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;
```

Comment: Changed the method as you advised  but Internal server error occuring `var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
                var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");               

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(USER_URL);
                var response = client.PostAsync("Users/Signin", content).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result;
                return false;`

Comment: What is internal server error? Your api is [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Users/Signin")] you're posting to "Users/Signin"